# progress dialog getting error in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

i have asynctask class and i try to send http request.i also use progress dialog but i can't show progress dialog.i have error
this is a my source

```
private class SendAccesssTokenToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            pDialog = null;
        }

        Log.e("Result issss", result + "res");

    }
}
```

this is a my logical error
[image]

how i can solve my problem ? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: `pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);` before  `pDialog.show();`

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the code wrongly. Check for the right code below:

```
private class SendAccesssTokenToServer extends
    AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{

    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading car. Please wait...");

    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    pDialog.show();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
{
     // dismiss the dialog after getting values

     pDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
}
```

First you show the progressDialog then assign another layout without dissmiss the previous progressDialog. Thas why you get that error.

Just change the code like this :-

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}
```

Hope this will help you :)